# Is it possible to dynamically generate makefile rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

There is an existing question with a similar sounding title. However, it is not quite what I am asking.

I find the following to be a typical use case:

```
items=Excelsior Shibboleth AbraCadabra

ceremony@%:
  foo bar biz baz $*

ritual@%:
  ding ring bing bong $*

ceremonies: $(foreach item,$(items),ceremony@$(item))
rituals: $(foreach item,$(items),ritual@$(item))

all: ceremonies | rituals
```

However, many of the `ceremonies` and `rituals` are time consuming and may be undesirable.  Also, `make` is most likely to be adopted and used when commands autocomplete and the file is not large.

What I want to do is dynamically define all the ritual and ceremony commands for the pre-defined items:

```
# pseudo code -- doesn't work in GNU Make 3.82 (my lowest version compatibility req)
$(foreach item,$(items),$(item)@ritual: ritual@$(item))
```

So that when you trigger tab completion, the itemized commands appear. And it will keep the makefile from getting too bulky.

Is this possible?

---

And the dual or "Y" problem is: if I have a wildcard rule, is it possible to generate some relevant matched rule results for display during tab completion in zsh/bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the code work using the `eval` function.  Change this:

```
$(foreach item,$(items),$(item)@ritual: ritual@$(item))
```

to this:

```
$(foreach item,$(items),$(eval $(item)@ritual: ritual@$(item)))
```

Without that, the result of this `foreach` expansion will be:

```
Excelsior@ritual: ritual@Excelsior Shibboleth@ritual ritual@Shibboleth AbraCadabra@ritual: ritual@AbraCadabra
```

which is clearly not a legal make statement.

Just to note, there is no such release as GNU make "3.8".  I don't know what release you might have.

Comment: `GNU Make 3.82, Built for x86_64-koji-linux-gnu` -- the reason I know this is my `define usage ... endef` directive started running make commands ╭( ๐_๐)╮

Comment: OK, yes, `3.82` is a valid make version.  But that is not the same as `3.8`.  There is no version `3.8`.  Anyway, `eval` was available in that version.

Comment: np; I will be distinct and complete going forward.